# Script reading column of .txt file

Tags: javascript, file, text, multiple-columns

I've got this script:

```
$.get('file.txt', function(x) {

    var i;
    var pos = 0;
    var availableTags = [];

    x = x.split(/[\;,\n]+/);

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i = i + 2)
        availableTags[pos++] = x[i];

    console.log(availableTags);

    $(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });

}, 'text');
```

I want it to read the first column of this file.txt

```
Airport;aeropuerto
Supermarket;supermercado
Station;estación;It can be a bus station, a train station, etc.
School;escuela
Shop;tienda;It can be a bookshop, a coffeshop, a toyshop, etc.
Chemist's;farmacia
```

The problem is that my script reads one element and skips the next, and I want it to read the first element of each line. This problem appears after the lines of three elements. Any solution?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like `i = i + 2` should actually be `i++`

Comment: The + 2 looks ok, if you had one semi-colon per line.`Station;estación;`, otherwise you need to change `/[\;,\n]+/`...

Comment: the file is 'word;translation', so the split will make 2 strings, hence the i=i+2, but on the third line there's an explanation after the second ; which is what causes the problem most likely.

Comment: Yes thats it, maybe the best is to introduce exta semicolon at the end of the others. Thnx 4 your help guys xxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file has a non-static number of columns in each row. With your method, you're splitting your file into a single array of each cell. Then you are assuming there are two cells per row, jumping forward two cells. But that assumption is false, as some rows have three cells.

Instead of splitting on newline and semicolon together, split first on newlines and then split on semicolons. This will give you an array of array of strings.

```
x = x.split("/n").map(function (row) { return row.split(";"); });
availableTags = x.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });
```

---

Full sample:

```
$.get('file.txt', function(file) {

  var table = file.split("/n").map(function (row) { return row.split(";"); });
  var availableTags = table.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });


console.log(availableTags);

$(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});

}, 'text');
```

---

BTW: Use the `push` method to push new elements to an array.

Instead of...

```
var pos = 0;
var arr = [];

for (var ix = 0; ix < 10; ix += 1) {
    arr[pos++] = ix;
}
```

do

```
var arr = [];

for (var ix = 0; ix < 10; ix += 1) {
    arr.push(ix);
}
```

---

If you can control the data file, I would make sure that all rows have the same number of columns. For columns that don't have any data, just put a semicolon or newline directly after it.